# linking from OnClick to iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick, hyperlink

I am attempting to have a link load an article from my domain in to an iframe. I understand that it is usually easy to link using:

`<a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.google.com');return false">Google</a>`

But when it comes to Iframes I am having difficulty formatting the code correctly so that it will display inside the iframe.

I can not use:

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="your_frame_name">Google</a>`

Because I need to use an onClick so I can execute more than one command.

I have tried iterations of:

`<A HREF="#" onclick="window.framename.location='page.htm';">text</A>`

`<A HREF="#" onClick="window.open('your url', 'frameName'); return false">text</a>`

`<A HREF="#" onclick="document.framename.location.href='page.htm'; return false">text</a>`

and none of them are doing anything.

Thank you in advance,

Spence

Comment: give an id to your iframe and find it by getElementById then assign its src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use link and do what ever you want to do in onclick event

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="your_frame_name" onclick="executeOnClick()">Google</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function executeOnClick(){

// add your logic here


return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Didn't even realize I could do that -- Can you tell this is my first site?

Comment: Edited and added a function definition, you can add your logic whatever you want to do in that function.